# moment js gets current time but not the created time

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I'm trying to retrieve the created_at time

but instead it renders the current time. which is not what i want.

I'm using laravel 5.5 in conjunction with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
 <p>   <% post.created_at | phpDate : "human"  %></p>
```

main.js

```
app.filter('phpDate', function() {
    // A filter declaration should return an anonymous function.
    // The first argument is the input passed to the filter
    // Any additional arguments are paramaters passed AFTER the filter name
    return function(input, format) {
        // Create an instance of Moment. Use both the
        // date value and timezone information PHP sent
        var date = moment.tz(input.date, input.timezone);

        if (format == "human") {
            // Special case for formatting. If user asks for "human" format
            // return a value like "13 minutes ago" or "2 weeks ago" etc.
            return moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar(); 
        } else {
            // Covert the moment to a string using the passed format
            // If nothing is passed, uses default JavaScript date format
            return moment().format('lll'); 
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What is <% %>? What is the value of post.created_at. Have you used your JavaScript debugger? Have you added `console.log()` statements in your filter to know what input contains, what date contains, etc.?

Comment: `post.created_at` is equal to the time the post was created. but the filter doesnt show that

Comment: where should i do console.log at

Comment: Well, in your pipe, where you have access to the input variable that you want to transform.

Comment: can you show me ? im not understanding

Comment: After `return function(input, format) {`, add `console.log('input = ', input);`. This is really basic JS stuff. You should learn this basic stuff before starting with AngularJS.

Comment: i didn't know you can  console log input, the input is showing the correct time when the post was made, but its not outputting on the blade file, instead it shows the current time on the blade file

Comment: I have no idea what a blade file is. You understand angularjs executes at client side, in the browser, right? Whetever your PHP does is completely irrelevant. What matters is the HTML template that is parsed and executed by AngularJS. What does the template file, as parsed by angularjs, contains? What is the value printed in the console?

Comment: `input =  2017-11-24 22:57:13`
 `input =  2017-11-25 08:29:30`
`input =  2017-11-25 08:30:44`

Comment: the correct time

Comment: OK. Now let's concentrate on one of these inputs. Pick the one you want. Tell us which one you picked, what the value of "format" is, what you expect as output, and what you actually have as output.

Comment: `moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();`

Comment: thats what i want outputted

Comment: So, you literally want your pipe to show, to the user looking at your page, the message `return moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();`? If not, what is the actual output you want? And again, what is the output you actually get? If the input is the string `"2017-11-24 22:57:13"`, why does your code expect this string to have a property "date" and a property "timezone"? Do you really think JavaScript strings have such properties?

Comment: no, i want to show the day it was posted. for example  November 24, 2017 8:30 AM

Comment: Then why are you telling me otherwise? Refresh and re-read my previous comment. I'm done with this thread.

Comment: @JBNizet did this question upset you that bad that you put me down, a leader with a reputation like yourself need to help others when needed. Our community thinks highly of you guys and i understand you barely get the respect and recognition that you deserve.

Comment: My point is not to offend anyone. Far from it. But you need to show some effort, and you're not, which is upsetting. You seem to lack the basic skills needed to start with AngularJS. So you should acquire them first, before asking questions. And even then, when I ask you simple questions, you don't answer them. So, sorry if I've offended you. Again, it was not the point. But I think I'm actually not doing you a favor by trying to help here, because you should really be able to do that by yourself, just by reading documentation and applying basic debugging techniques.

Comment: show me the way, guide me so i can best help myself in the future, i am lost without direction or guidance, i stumble and my path is not so clear. lay the ground work in which i can understand please

Comment: we fixed it thank you

Answer (score 0):

with the help of a highly respectable user on this site we were able to fix it, just needed add input within moment parathesis.

```
app.filter('phpDate', function() {

    return function(input, format) {

        if (format == "human") {

            // add input then it works

            return moment(input).subtract(1, 'days').calendar(); 
        } else {

            return moment().format('lll'); 
        }
    };
});
```